# Where to put text files in an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project using Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-content

I am working on a dynamic web project in Eclipse with Tomcat 7. All of my html, css and javascript files are inside the **WebContent** folder in the eclipse workspace. All the java files are inside the **src** folder. All works well for simple programs. But now I want to read a text file from the java programs. I am not sure where to put the text file in the eclipse workspace so that it is correctly deployed to the Tomcat webapps directory inside ./metadata folder of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServletContext.getResourceAsStream() API.

An example can be found at [this link](http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/how-to-use-servletcontextgetresourceasstreamjavalangstring-path/18) . It suggests that the file should be kept in the /WEB-INF directory

Comment: i want to use the file in a separate class which i will call from the servlet

Comment: `URL url = this.getClass().getResource( "/stop.txt" );` returns null although my `stop.txt` file is present in WEB-INF folder

Answer (score -1):

put ur files inside webroot folder or outside webroot folder any where it is possible to read files .

inside **classes folder** is good because of default **classpath** for webapplication

Comment: how do i access the file using relative pathnames?

Comment: directely give ur filename ,suppose hi.txt isthere in clasees folder then "hi.txt" u r relative for inside classes folder.

Comment: where u r java class is existing